Is there a definitive conclusion on the existence of constrained solutions for underdetermined systems of equations?
First, illustrate the meaning of a so-called definitive conclusion with an example. Example: An overdetermined system of equations either has a unique solution or no solution. When there is no solution, the best approximate solution can be found using the least squares method. This is a conclusion!
Question:
Assume there is an underdetermined system of equations:
0.7196, 0.0694, 0.5264, 0.1107      x1         0
                                        =
1.8332, 0.3779, 1.4690, 0.4547      x2         0

                                    x3

                                    x4

with the requirements that x1 is a positive integer, x2 is a negative integer, and both x3 and x4 are integers.
Is there a "definitive" conclusion regarding the existence of such a solution? For instance, can it be proven that such a solution definitely exists or definitely does not exist?
If it can be proven that no solution exists, could the method for finding an approximate solution for the underdetermined system be explained geometrically? (For example, the approximate solution for an overdetermined system is actually the projection of the vector on the right-hand side onto the column space of the system of equations!)
I’m not very familiar with the geometric principles behind approximate solutions for underdetermined systems of equations. Therefore, I also find it difficult to understand the underlying principle of the following code in MATLAB that finds approximate solutions. I’m not sure how to modify this code to obtain a solution that meets the requirements Bolded text. I asked GPT for modifications, but the resulting solutions either meet the Bolded text requirements but produce a zero vector with poor precision when right-multiplies the matri C, or they produce a zero vector with high precision but with solutions that are not all integers
%The following code can only achieve x_1 > 0, x_2 < 0, x_3 < 0, x_4 > 0 .
C = [0.7196, 0.0694, 0.5264, 0.1107;
     1.8332, 0.3779, 1.4690, 0.4547];
d = [0; 0];

% Equality constraints
Aeq = [];
beq = [];

% Inequality constraints, requiring the first variable to be greater than zero, the second variable to be less than zero, the third variable to be less than zero, and the fourth variable to be greater than zero.
A = [-1 0 0 0;  % x1 > 0  ->  -x1 < 0
      0 1 0 0;  % x2 < 0  ->   x2 < 0
      0 0 1 0;  % x3 < 0  ->   x3 < 0
      0 0 0 -1]; % x4 > 0  ->  -x4 < 0
b = [0; 0; 0; 0];

% Optimization options
options = optimoptions('lsqlin', 'MaxIterations', 1000, 'OptimalityTolerance', 1e-10, 'StepTolerance', 1e-10);

% Call the `lsqlin` function.
n = lsqlin(C, d, A, b, Aeq, beq, [], [], [], options);

